# Observer with Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

So mathematically I understand what happens when we go from Schwarzschild metric to Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates in describing black holes. what I don't understand is the physical interpretation. For example, if I am given a Lorentz transformation, I can see it describe two observant with relative uniform velocity, but I can not do that with Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates.
In other words, is there any special observer with any kind of relative motion to the Schwarzschild observer, whose description of events follows Schwarzschild to Kruskal-Szekeres coordinate transformation? 
PS_I have already seen this, but still I have problem.
[Physical interpretation of Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/405743/physical-interpretation-of-kruskal-szekeres-coordinates/405754#405754)

Comment: Unlike the Schwarzschild (distant) or Gullstrand–Painleve (raindrop) coordinates, the Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates do not represent space or time measured by any physical observer and therefore have no direct physical meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All coordinates are just human conventions used to describe events in spacetime. Nothing more is possible in curved space time. This is just as true of Schwarzschild coordinates, in which the radial coordinate does not describe a physical distance, but is simply calculated from the angle subtended by a length of arc.